# IOS Phonegap Functionality not working first time

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, window.location

I am opening one url in inapp browser. when i return from inappbrowser to my phonegap app. phonegap function like camera,gallery or even device ready is not working. but when i send app in background and resume it then all the functionality is wokring. :(

Where in Android all working fine but in ios not.

I have 3 html pages.from index.html i am opening the page in inappbrowser after i am comming to second.html in which i had use all functionality like camera,gallery.

I had used winload.location for redirection...

I had try lot.

Please Help me .... :(

Comment: you have got any solution for this?

Comment: No i am still facing issue... :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem some time ago. 
To me was related to the settings of the camera. I used following settings:

```
 quality: 50, // or less for ios as in specifications,
 destinationType: parent.window.Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, // ! Important
```

Regards